# How to relate user collection with other data collection in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am making a Todo List website with node.js and using mongoose database. In this database I have two two collecions,

1. user colllection having schema like this :
   const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   email: String,
   password: String,
   googleId: String
   });
2. list collection to store list items having schema like :
   const itemsSchema = {
   name: String
   }
   How to ensure that if a user is logged in then the item it enters in todolist belogs to him/her only ?

Answer (score 1):

In user.js add:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const itemsSchema = { 
  name: String,
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  }
}
```